# how to use Beautifulsoup4 to check if parent tag has a direct child whose name is not "div"

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to check if parent tag has a direct child whose name is not "div", so I'd like to check all the direct children of a tag. I tried like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://beautifulsoup.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/v4.4.0/#contents-children'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36')
website = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = website.read()
with open("web.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html.decode())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.contents:
    print(item.name)
```

The project is a little complex, so I create this small test file. I remembered this is right when I used this package last year. However when I run this code with python3.6 BeautifulSoup4.4.0, the output is like this:

[image]

I tried all of the parser

```
    BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
    BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
    BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")
    BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")
```

but they are all wrong. And the html.parser even print the worst output :(
So my question is how to get the children correctly? I only want the direct children.

---------------------10 MIN LATER------------------
I tried to modify this test code to:

```
for item in soup.body.contents:
    print(item.name)
```

and I get the names of other tags with "None" between them:
   [image]

AFAIC, maybe this is because the 
 or &nbsp is parsed, but I don't know how to solve this

Comment: What is the output that you want?

Comment: all the tag names except None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK, but with `soup.contents` you are selecting root `<html>` tag and some plain `NavigableString` objects, whose names are `None`. Try to select some tags inside the soup, e.g. selecting all `h3`:

```
for item in soup.select('h3'):
    print(item.text)
```

Will print:

```
Name¶
Attributes¶
tag的名字¶
.contents 和 .children¶
.descendants¶
.string¶
.strings 和 stripped_strings¶
.parent¶
.parents¶
.next_sibling 和 .previous_sibling¶
.next_siblings 和 .previous_siblings¶
.next_element 和 .previous_element¶
.next_elements 和 .previous_elements¶
字符串¶
正则表达式¶
列表¶
True¶
方法¶
name 参数¶
keyword 参数¶
按CSS搜索¶
string 参数¶
limit 参数¶
recursive 参数¶
智能引号¶
矛盾的编码¶
需要的解析器¶
方法名的变化¶
生成器¶
XML¶
实体¶
迁移杂项¶
```

Edit:

To check if `<div>` tag has any child, whose name is not `div`, you could use lambda function:

```
for div_tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    if div_tag.find(lambda t: t.name != 'div'):
        print(div_tag.text)
        print('-' * 80)
```

EDIT 2:

To check if `<div>` tag has any **direct** child, whose name is not `div`, you could use lambda function and CSS selector:

```
for div_tag in soup.select('div > *'):
    if div_tag.find(lambda t: t.name != 'div'):
        print(div_tag.text)
        print('-' * 80)
```

Comment: well, thank you, but I read the doc and found that in theory, there is a and only a child for soup, it's "html" (in fact, I think here soup is an object with the entire website with a and only a tag called <html>).

Comment: so I don't agree with you that" `soup.contents` you are not selecting any tags

Comment: @Forsworn But what are you trying to do? To find concrete tag you need to find it, with `find()` or other method. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you， but I want to check if a "div" tag has children tags other than <div>,

Comment: it means that I want to check if parent tag has a child whose name is not "div"

Comment: @Forsworn you could use lambda function for that, see my edited answer. And edit your question also, to make it clear for others.

Comment: I still do not get his/her question completely to be honest.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have edited my question, but wait a while, let me think about your words, I only want to check the direct children, so I want to modify your answer, if it works, I will come back and close this problem

Comment: @Forsworn Then use CSS selector: `for div_tag in soup.select('div > *')`. This selects all tags, whose parent is `div`. I edit my answer.

Comment: THANKS!! it is better to think inversely, but there may be  `div div div` so there should be a verification of parent, it's complex and slow but I think we have no choice. this is my homework :(

Comment: I found another way to solve this problem, I don't know whether it's useful to @ you in the answer, so reply here to tell you

Answer (score 1):

wow, I think I found another way:
in fact, we only need to check the type of the object when we use the soup.contents or soup.children:

```
from bs4.element import Tag

for child in soup.children:
    print(type(child))
    print(type(child) == Tag)
    print('-' * 80)
```

in this way, we can get the direct children of tag while neglect the `NavigableString` or something else
that is:

```
for child in soup.children:
    if type(child) == Tag:
        print(child.name)
```

Comment: or `if isinstance(child, Tag)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular filter to filter out the `div`

`if td.parent.find_all(re.compile("[^(div)]")):`